# Problem with adding custom words to hunspell dictionary in R

Tags: r, dictionary, hunspell

I was able to figure out how to add custom words into the `hunspell` dictionary in R. However, I'm not sure why it's not being used in spell checking. Here is what I used:

```
library(hunspell)
#adding custom words into hunspell dictionary
hunspell::dictionary(lang = "en_US", affix = NULL, add_words = "bing", cache = TRUE)
```

but `hunspell("bing")` still determine "bing" is incorrect.

Anyone have experience with this before? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dictionary()` function returns a new dictionary that you can use. It doesn't change the default behavior or anything. You can do

```
library(hunspell)
mydict <- dictionary(lang = "en_US", affix = NULL, add_words = "bing", cache = TRUE)
hunspell("bing", dict=mydict)
```