# Add custom words manually in Hunspell dictionary in R

Tags: r, dictionary, hunspell

I need to add custom words in hunspell dictionary so that the next time I use it it won't show an error for the same word.

I went through code mentioned [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56043887/problem-with-adding-custom-words-to-hunspell-dictionary-in-r)

The following code is storing the dict in a variable but I want to write the existing dictionary with the updated one.

```
library(hunspell)
mydict <- dictionary(lang = "en_US", affix = NULL, add_words = "bing", cache = TRUE)
hunspell("bing", dict=mydict)
```

I want `bing`  to be included in dict `en_US`.

Comment: which line of code shows you an error now?

Comment: It not showing any error. this code is working fine but I am not bale to add words in dictionary file. like "bing" should be added to "en_US.dic" file